# django restframework: how to efficiently search on many to many related fields?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Given these models:

```
    class B:

        my_field = TextField()


    class A:
        b = ManyToMany(B)
```

I have +50K rows in `A`, when searching for elements I want to do full text searches on `my_field` by traversing the many to many field `b` (i.e. `b__my_field`).

This works fine when the number of many to many elements `B`per `A` object is less than ~3. How ever if I have something greater than that performance drops impressively.

Wondering if I could do some sort of prefetch related search? Is something like haystack my only option?

Comment: Is this query fast? `B.objects.filter(my_field__contains='search text')`

Comment: Do you have performance problem in Django or in Database. How many queries django generate for one search request?

Answer (score 0):

When you loop through a query set, django makes a database request for each step of your loop. See [this](https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2016/02/21/building-high-performance-django-systems/) for exampleon ORM pitfalls. A thing that you should learn when using django ORM is to use commands to avoid database roundtrips as much as possible. One way to do that is with values() function. Ideally you should get only what you need too. 
Try this:

```
l = list(A.b.all().values('my_field'))
```

This guarantees only one database query, and return a list that you can loop through in python speed. Should be much faster.